Is the image rotation function (as seen in Word or PowerPoint) a Group?
I have been thinking of this problem for a while now, but can't seem to figure it out. We are all familiar with adding an image in a PowerPoint file, say for example, a square. We can rotate however we want and regardless of the angle, it always appears the same (as in no obvious scaling seen).
My question is related to Group Theory - whatever function or mapping is behind this rotation-action, it surely must be form a Group, right? I really want to figure out what the underlying mathematics behind this rotation is and if it could form a Group.
Any suggestions where I could start? I have been struggling with finding literature related to this topic, so would appreciate any ideas!
Thanks a lot!

It is only a group if the rotation is by an angle that is exactly of the form M*pi/N. Otherwise it never returns to the original no matter how many times you apply it.

not a programming question. the [math.se] SE might be a better place to ask this.

Great question, although as noted it's off topic here. You may be interested in "symmetry groups". A web search will find some resources. Good luck and have fun.
